# How to connect putHQL in apache nifi

Tags: apache-nifi, hortonworks-data-platform, azure-hdinsight

I am trying to connect to hive on hdinsight . these are the steps that i have followed
     1.created a text file and inserted a create table statement
     2.converted it to flowfile using getFile processor. This flow file will
       be input to puthiveQL processor
when i try to execute this dataflow it throws error as shown in the image attached.

[image]

Comment: Could you share the processor configuration and the content of the FlowFile you are trying to pass to the processor?